# Getting R could not be resolved by a variable when importing HoloEverywhere

Tags: android, eclipse, import, android-actionbar, android-holo-everywhere

So i have ActioanBar and Viewflow fully implemented in my app.
I have been reading that HoloEverywhere needs actionbar, so that should not be any problems...
It happends right after i have choosen, Properties --> Android --> Add --> Holo lib

Then after rebuilding i get the error: R could not be resolved.
I have tried cleaning my project and so on.

It happens right after i have imported the library..

Thanks for any help